# convert rows into columns in sql server with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have this result

| Visitor name | City | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Neo | Japan | 95,000 |
| Neo | NewYork | 100,000 |
| Neo | Paris | 1,000,000 |

I want to get this result

| Visitor name | Japan | NewYork | Paris |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Neo | 95,000 | 100,000 | 1,000,000 |

Comment: You can use a [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) query

Comment: i khnow, but i dont khnow how to use it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761712/sql-server-how-to-transpose-rows-to-columns-without-pivot-or-unpivot-or-aggrega use crossaplly

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT V.Visitor_name,
SUM
  (
     CASE  
       WHEN V.CITY='Japan' THEN V.PRICE
       ELSE 0.00 
     END
  )AS JAPAN,
SUM
 (
   CASE  
     WHEN V.CITY='NewYork' THEN V.PRICE
     ELSE 0.00 
   END
 )AS NewYork,
SUM
(
   CASE  
    WHEN V.CITY='Paris' THEN V.PRICE
    ELSE 0.00 
   END
)AS Paris
FROM YOUR_TABLE AS V
GROUP BY V.Visitor_name
```

If cities names are unknown, then please google "dynamic pivot"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) solution:

```
SELECT VISITOR_NAME,[Japan],[NewYork],[Paris]
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE) AS S
PIVOT
(SUM(PRICE)
FOR CITY IN ([Japan],[NewYork],[Paris])
) AS P
```

Test Sample:

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e511de11adb2ab5a1d972ed047574aa)